# Should I use mongodb/SQL Server context with scope or singleton?

Tags: c#, sql-server, mongodb, asp.net-core-7.0

I want to access db mongo/SQL Server in the most effective way.

From my perspective, I will just use context as singleton and that's  all.

I worked before at a company where they use all the logic services as singleton but all the inside db connection made one time like :

```
using var db = new DBContext("DBName");
```

So why to work like that if I can use a singleton?

Answer (score 1):

A DbContext is not a database connection.  A DbContext will open and close database connections as needed.  Your DbContext can be a singleton only if

1. Your application guarantees that it's only accessed by one thread at a time.
2. You manage the Change Tracker to keep it from growing over time, eg with [ChangeTracker.Clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.changetracker.clear?view=efcore-7.0).

The DbContext is intended to be scoped to a Unit-of-work in your application. In Win Forms, WCF, or Console app it's possible to do this.  In any kind of web app it's not really feasible.

Answer (score 1):

DbContext, DbConnection, MongoDb or RavendDB Session, all these kind of things should be scoped. They may not be singleton for a simple reason: they are not thread safe. Singleton services must be thread safe.

Comment: what about the answer here - It is recommended to store a MongoClient instance in a global place, either as a static variable or in an IoC container with a singleton lifetime
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703051/properly-shutting-down-mongodb-database-connection-from-c-sharp-2-1-driver